# How do I stop someone who is fetching more than one Iframe in their page of my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I stop someone who is fetching more than one Iframe in their page of my website.
 Is their any way to stop using php or javascript.pls help me. thanks.

Comment: Did you think about logging the client's IP and limiting the page they can get?

Comment: No I dont know.Can u help me please...@Guy3000

Comment: Please be more spacific about what you are asking. improve your question adding a few more details.

Comment: if they load single i frame its ok.but they are loading more than one iframe.so I just want to show only single i frame not multiple.thank you ...@CodingHorror

Comment: how do i allow a single iframe for my website for a page